# How to create Seo Friendly URL use Mod_Rewrite module Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's an example link to my website: https://www.example.com/contact.php?ccode=US

Where the `US` sets the website language; my website has multilingual support.
I Need to transform link to look like this: https://www.example.com/us/

What rules do I need to write in .htaccess to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /contact.php?ccode=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the desired URL. Just make sure you **reset your cache** before testing it.